# Python "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bindings'" error only when I compile my code

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I can run my code on both normal Python IDLE and Visual Studio Code but the executable that was compiled with same Python installation's pyinstaller gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MyApp.py", line 40, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
  File "tkinterweb\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bindings'
[4712] Failed to execute script MyApp
```

I already have installed `bindings` module by `pip`.

Also I was imported `from tkinterweb import HtmlFrame` in line 40. What can I do? Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this has been answered on [Github](https://github.com/Andereoo/TkinterWeb/issues/14), but I'll add the answer here for anyone having trouble with this issue and stumbling across this page at some point in the future.

1. Upgrade to the latest version of both TkinterWeb AND PyInstaller. It will not work if you aren't fairly recent versions.
2. Then use the `--collect-all tkinterweb` flag when bundling your app. For example, if you are using `pyinstaller --windowed yourscript.py` instead run `pyinstaller --windowed --collect-all tkinterweb yourscript.py`. This tells PyInstaller to include the TkinterWeb files. On many popular packages, this `--collect-all` command isn't necessary, because PyInstaller has extra files (called hooks) that tell it what to do if it encounters certain packages. PyInstaller does not come with a hook for TkinterWeb, so you simply have to tell it to include the necessary TkinterWeb files manually.

That's all!